# .htaccess 301 redirect does not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I have a website using PHP-based CMS system.

So each page is generated dynamically, like this :

http://www.shuling.net.cn/index.php?_m=mod_product&_a=view&p_id=87

Now I want to redirect this specific page to another page, i.e.:

- https://www.datanumen.com/sql-recovery/

So I write .htaccess file as follows :

```
redirect 301 /index.php?_m=mod_product&_a=view&p_id=87 https://www.datanumen.com/sql-recovery/
```

But after I upload the .htaccess to the root directory of the website, this does not work at all.

I retest by writing another rule, like this:

```
redirect 301 /sql/ https://www.datanumen.com/sql-recovery/
```

Then this rule will work perfectly.

Why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querystring is not part of match in Redirect directive, to redirect query strings, you need to use mod-rewrite as follows :

**option 1**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?_m=mod_product&_a=view&p_id=87 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.datanumen.com/sql-recovery/? [NC,L,R]
```

**option 2**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_m=mod_product&_a=view&p_id=87$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.datanumen.com/sql-recovery/? [NC,L,R]
```

We use an empty question mark **?** at the end of the target url to discard the old query strings, otherwise these query strings get appened to the target url by default.

Change the **R** to **R=301** if you want to make the redirection permanent.

[Tested on apache2 and 2.4]